# Azure ServiceBus Trigger - Start Time - 28+ Seconds

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have an Azure ServiceBus Trigger, (Functions App with the following function)

```
module.exports = function(context, message) {
    context.log('Message ', message);
    context.done();
};
```

which has the following configuration,

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "message",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "topicName": "topictest",
      "subscriptionName": "sbsub1",
      "connection": "testsb_RootManageSharedAccessKey_SERVICEBUS",
      "accessRights": "Manage"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Do you guess what is the start time for this function? It is taking 28+ seconds. It is not just the first instance, any new instance it spins it takes the almost a very long time (greater than 1 second). Few sample timings (28, 43, 93 seconds). No time consistency. Horrible platform to work with unless I make some blender mistakes in my code.

There are no external libraries, not too many other files to process any business logic. It is a very simple function.

What am I doing wrong here?  Does implementing it under a different language help to improve performance?

Comment: Are you using the Classic app service plan or the consumption plan? I assumed that you could use a dedicated plan (Basic/Standard/Premium) and turn on **Always On** to narrow this issue. Moreover, I found a github issue talking about the similar issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/298), you could refer to it.

Comment: I'm using consumption plan. Will try that out.

Comment: Those seem like abnormal numbers if you have no dependencies. Can you share your function app name (that's the **app** name, not function name!), either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately)? Also, include the UTC time of some abnormally slow requests. This will help us investigate.

Comment: Dedicated Plan worked with less time (9, 12 seconds). Tried Eventhub and works better than ServiceBus with startup time and performance. I think will stick with Eventhub.